# Django Admin reverse inline many-to-many extremely slow to load

Tags: django, django-admin

I have three models Organisation, Event and EventReport. Event and EventReport have a many to many relationship. An Event is only ever associated with a single Organisation. An Event may have many EventReports and a EventReport may be related to multiple Events.

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.TextField()
    url = models.URLField()
    ...

class Event(models.Model):
    ...
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name = "events")

    event_reports = models.ManyToManyField(EventReport, blank=True)
    ...

class EventReport(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    summary = models.TextField()
```

My objective is to see all of the Events that a particular EventReport is linked to. This is a reverse Many-to-Many relationship, so I am using a "through" model. I've configured admin.py as follows:

```
class EventInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Event.event_reports.through

class EventReportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields=['date','summary']
    inlines = [
        EventInLine,
    ]
```

When loading an EventReport in Admin.. it works but takes an extremely long amount of time to load.

The EventReport page does list multiple Events under a section called:
"EVENT-EVENTREPORT RELATIONSHIPS"

Each associated Event is represented in a single dropdown as a Event object e.g.
event_event_reports object (10487) with the **STR** representation of each object in the dropdown.

I believe the large amount of time is due to populating the dropdown box with every Event in the database for each inline Event object. I do not need the inlines to be editable, so have also experimented with read-only fields but am unable to get the right config for this.

Any guidance on how to configure the inline to reduce load times appreciated.